# Extender provider for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there an equivalent to the [System.ComponentModel.IExtenderProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx) geered toward WPF ?

Do I have to go toward Dependency Properties and Attached Properties to build an equivalent, or is there already something baked in the oven waiting for me ?

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Attached Property is the way to go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx

You can also use AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildrenAttribute to tell a control to extend the newly created property to all its children (Has Grid's row property).

Answer (score 0):

The **WPF** reader and writer for **XAML** have no awareness of the `System.ComponentModel.Container` concept used in **Windows Forms**. **XAML** deploys a comprehensive system of **XamlType** types, including **XamlMember**, **XamlPropery**, etc., all unified under a **XamlSchemaContext**, and which together represent a full-blown type system superimposed over--and largely independent of--the **.NET** type system (i.e., "reflection"). **XAML** "attached properties" are only defined *by-and-within* this universe and are therefore existentially confined to it.

While some of this is unrelated to `System.ComponentModel` really, it is indeed unfortunate that these two major architectural frameworks do not, in fact conspire, communicate, or collude to collectively correlate, conflate or co-opt the concepts they ***do*** contain in common.

The good news, however--and the reason for this tardy post, and the answer to your question--is that **XamlServices** *does* have extension points to address your scenario. Because all of those "**Xaml...**" type-types I mentioned above are represented by public classes that are not sealed and can be overridden. The starting point is to create your own customized `XamlSchemaContext` and override `GetXamlType` method to provide your own customized **XamlType**-derived objects wherever your situation requires.

**XamlType** is where you can intercept, modify, or inject, whatever attached property behavior you want. See the `LookupAttachableMember` or `LookupAllAttachableMembers` method overrides. A method in your **XamlType** implementation which might be of particular interest to override is `XamlType.LookupInvoker(...)`, which allows you to supply a customized **XamlTypeInvoker** instance which, in turn, has a `CreateInstance(...)` override that can ultimately control any/all aspects of the instance(s) deployed to the resulting deserialized object graph.

In the extreme, `XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance` can substitute some or all of the XAML-resolved CLR types entirely, but this starts to defeat the larger purpose, since any such "replacement" CLR types--just like all CLR types instantiated by **XamlServices**--must always have a pre-existing CLR definition. In other words, what XAML *does **not** do*--but you could certainly add via this override!--is use reflection `TypeBuilder` etc., to *synthesize* new types or members that do not already have a CLR `Type` equivalent.

> *To be clear,* this means that there's no way to  get **WPF** to recognize any sort of putative "synthetic" customized type instance, nor data-bind to "virtual" runtime properties, via just manipulating **XamlType** or **XamlMember** alone.

Meanwhile, once you've overridden types and properties and other members to create your own derived **XAML** type system under your derived **XamlSchemaContext**, you can supply an instance of that schema to the **XAML** reader and writer methods in **XamlServices**.

You can pass your custom XAML schema context into the constructors for the standard **XAML** readers/writers, such as **XamlXmlReader** and **XamlObjectWriter** (for the so-called "load path" scenario; I won't discuss the "save path" here).  More importantly, however, you can also override these two classes as well, and they provide a rich set of virtual methods to override. As a pseudo-code example (lifted from my working code), you can add a `transform(...)` method to your `XamlXmlReader`-derived class that provides full control of a XAML deserialized `object` result:

```
// ...in your class derived from 'XamlXmlReader'
public void transform(my_xaml_obj_writer xow)
{
    while (base.Read())
    {
        if (xow.ShouldProvideLineInfo)
            xow.SetLineInfo(LineNumber, LinePosition);

        switch (NodeType)
        {
            case XamlNodeType.NamespaceDeclaration:
                xow.WriteNamespace(base.Namespace);
                break;

            case XamlNodeType.StartObject:
                xow.WriteStartObject(base.Type);
                break;

            case XamlNodeType.EndObject:
                xow.inject_ctor_arg();    // <--- !! (not shown)
                xow.WriteEndObject();
                break;

            case XamlNodeType.StartMember:
                xow.inject_ctor_arg();    // <--- !! (not shown)
                xow.WriteStartMember(base.Member);
                break;

            case XamlNodeType.EndMember:
                xow.WriteEndMember();
                break;

            case XamlNodeType.GetObject:
                xow.WriteGetObject();
                break;

            case XamlNodeType.Value:
                xow.WriteValue(base.Value);
                break;

            case XamlNodeType.None:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this custom reader, the process of deserializing **XAML** to an in-memory CLR object is something like this:

```
void XamlToObject(FileStream fs, my_xaml_schema_context ctx)
{
    using (var xxr = new xaml_xml_reader(fs, ctx))
    using (var xow = new my_obj_writer(this))
    {
        try
        {
            xxr.transform(xow);
        }
        catch (XamlObjectWriterException xex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting XAML "root object", the in-memory CLR object which is the whole point, will be found on the `Result` property of your overridden **XamlObjectWriter** at the end of this process. In my case, I actually snoop the result object out of the XAML node stream earlier during the `transform` method shown above, as soon as it is created, in order to see if it has the `[UsableDuringInitialization]` attribute, and accordingly enable certain concurrent uses while the deserialization is still in progress.

Finally note that **XamlObjectWriterSettings** and **XamlXmlReaderSettings** can also be overridden with your own derived classes, if you want to add additional settings. More commonly you might just need to do this in order to make additional custom data available to yourself, since with overridden methods in **XamlServices** you tend to sometimes find yourself deep within the bowels of a callback while seemingly having insufficient contextual information.